# RESTful API with Users and Authentication via Google OAuth2?

Tags: node.js, rest, api, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm kinda new to backend development and wanted to start by creating a small API with authentication and authorization that could function as an API for a blog for different frontend implementations.

I set up an API with ExpressJS and MongoDB and created a working API so I can post blog-posts, retreive all or single blog posts, etc.

Now I wanted to add Authentication and instead of using JWT or something, I thought, it could be cool to have my users sign in via their Google-Account to post/delete blog posts, etc. Does that even make sense? I hope it does because in my head it should not differ too much from using JWT for example.

I added passport.js and it's google-oauth2 strategy.

I'm already able to create users by signing in via google, but my problem lies in the way to authenticate correctly for login and subsequent API requests.

Would I use the access- and refresh-token that I receive back from google for that? At least thats what I first thought of.

But how would that work? And next up: What if I wanted to add another way to authenticate? For example JWT or maybe Facebook-OAuth? Wouldn't that cause some issues when trying to protect my API routes because I would have different ways of authenticating (and what kind of middleware would I use then for my routes?)

I hope I made my problem clear :)

Comment: Using a 3rd party OAuth for sign-in doesn't replace your own need for managing credentials for your data. The credentials you get from Google in this case would only be used to talk to *Google's* API, not your own! You basically use the fact that you can log the user in as validation of their identity, and the resulting email/account ID as a unique identifier you can associate with the user. You'll still need some way to validate subsequent requests to your own services, which could be your own JWT or something from Google's response that you can validate on each request to your API.

Comment: "You'll still need some way to validate subsequent requests to your own services, which could be your own JWT or something from Google's response that you can validate on each request to your API."

So would it be a good practice to sign a JWT as soon as someone logged in with their google account? Or would I use googles Access token for that?

Comment: I'd create a JWT upon successful Google login, and pass that back to the client. Unless you're going to make Google API requests on behalf of the logged in user, I wouldn't even store their Google information (though I'd use their email or google id as the identifier in the JWT and for storing per-user data in my own API).

Comment: That's how I thought of it in my last comment :) I'm trying to implement and then maybe send you the github link. Maybe you can quickly check if I did anything terribly wrong :P I'm always concerned about security issues when coding for backend.

Comment: @bscotchAdam so I finished it and it seems to work. Now I'm just curious if I did anything really bad (like security wise or bad practice wise). Here's the repo: https://github.com/SVAR7BERG/restapi Maybe you could take a look? Just tell me how I can +rep you here afterwards :)